# How to produce plot with text as ytick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am just getting to know the Python libraries `pandas` and `matplotlib`. Can you show me as an example how to produce a plot similar to this one with `matplotlib`:

[image]

On the y-axis to the right the names of the data instances are listed. The x-axis below is for some value related to each instance.

The data is in .csv format similar to this:

```
name;value1;value2
uk-2007-05;0.01;1000
```

Ideally, both `value1` and `value2` should be plotted in the same plot with different colors or markers.

Comment: That looks like a simple x/y point chart rotated 90 degrees

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645946/imshow-labels-as-any-function-of-the-image-indices/12654847#12654847

Comment: Post a link to the dataset please.

Comment: How a title like that can help others to find their answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = [chr(j) for j in range(97, 115)]

fake_data1 = [random.random() for l in labels]
fake_data2 = [random.random() for l in labels]
y_data = range(len(labels))

figure()
ax = gca()

ax.grid(True)
ax.scatter(fake_data1, y_data, color='r')
ax.scatter(fake_data2, y_data, color='b')

ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.invert_xaxis()
plt.draw()
```

Where `labels` is a list of your labels, `y_data` is indices of the labels for each data point, and `fake_data1` and `fake_data2` are you `x` values.

[image: output]

Comment: +1 On a side note, explicitly setting the formatters and locators is probably overkill for something like this.

Comment: @JoeKington You are probably right.  I expanded/simplified the answer.

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks. Can I also put the labels on the right side of the plot and remove the `1.2` and `-0.2` marks?

Comment: @cls 1) `ax.yaxis.tick_right()` and 2) just adjust the x-limit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib/14406447#14406447